# Develop environment requirement for SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio

I am just starting on SharePoint and came to know that it is not as easy as another .net project where we just download Visual Studio community edition and start working on an application like web API and MVC with SQL express edition.

Now my question is, Is there any way I can start learning(practical development) in my local dev machine which is Windows 10, Visual Studio 2016 and MS SQL Server Developer edition. Or Do I have to download Windows Server and what else?

Answer (score 2):

As usual my answer will be it depends...

The need for SharePoint installation on your dev box is not something you SHOULD need anymore. The need for a "local" SharePoint is only there if you plan to deploy full trust solutions (which you should not)

You should consider using the add in model, which does not require a local SharePoint anymore. You can get away with using CSOM / REST in order to do most of your work. So you should be fine with a windows 10 box and visual studio.

You SharePoint should be a Dev O365 Platform, so your solutions will be compatible with the cloud right away. Dont try to use the old style server code any more.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about "SharePoint should be a Dev O365" or point me to some tutorial where I can start. As I said I am experienced Developer but not familiar with stack in Sharepoint and it's technical jargon

Comment: You can create a free developer site in Office365 to test your solutions, so there is no need to host your own SharePoint. If you only create client side code you will be able to host the solution online (You cant deploy full trust code there) Have a look at Pattern and Practices for SharePoint (PNP)

Answer (score 0):

The [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx#section4) give you the right advice:

- Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2016. No Windows 10!
- SQL-Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1, Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RTM or Microsoft SQL Server 2017 RTM for Windows
- SQL-Edition: Standard, Enterprise or Developer. SQL Server Express is not supported. SQL Azure (the SaaS service) is also not supported for any SharePoint databases
- SharePoint should also be hosted in a Domain-Environment, even if Workgroup-Joined Systems are technically possible.
- For a DEV-Environment, it is technically possible to install everything on one machine (ActiveDirectory, SQL-Server, SharePoint, VisualStudio and Tools). Such an installation is NOT supported for productive use!